# Java Date - How to write "If date A is later than date B"

Tags: java

I'm asked to write an expiry method for a policy that expires in exactly one year after it's added. I already wrote the method that adds one year to the initial date it was added.

Now I'm trying to write another method that returns a boolean to see if Date A is past Date B. If it's past, it means it's expired, so it'll return true. Can someone help me out with the Syntax, not sure what to do here. Thank you

```
public ExpirablePolicy(float a, Date d){
    super(a);
    amount = a;
    expiryDate = new Date();
    GregorianCalendar aCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    aCalendar.add(Calendar.YEAR,1);
    expiryDate = aCalendar.getTime();
} 

public boolean isExpired(){
    //expiry method;
```

Comment: `Date.before`? `Date.after`? `Date.compareTo`? Have you looked at the `Date` API docs? Or search something like "java date comparison" or something?

Comment: Take a look at the [Javadoc of the Date class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) and it should be pretty obvious.

Answer (score 6):

This can be done with [`Date.before()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#before%28java.util.Date%29) or [`Date.after()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after%28java.util.Date%29):

```
if (d.after(expiryDate)) { ... }
```

or

```
if (!d.before(expiryDate)) { ... }
```

The first comparison evaluates to `true` is `d` is strictly greater than `expiryDate`. The second evaluates to `true` if `d` is greater than or equal to `expiryDate`.

The same effect can be achieved with [`Date.compareTo()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo%28java.util.Date%29).

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
public boolean isExpired(Date a, Date b) {
    return a.before(b);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check java.util.Date. It has a method called compareTo.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo(java.util.Date)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [**Date.compareTo(Date)**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo%28java.util.Date%29) method:

```
public boolean isExpired(Date d1, Date d2) {
    return d1.compareTo(d2) > 0;
}
```

Comment: So if d1 is either less than, or greater than, d2 it's expired? That doesn't seem right; can you explain further?

Comment: @DaveNewton if `d1 is before d2` compareTo returns a positive number and if `d1 is after d2` it returns a negetive number. note that `||` will not evaluate the second expression if the first one is true.

Comment: Only one condition matters; why put both in the expression? Even if both *did* matter, why wouldn't you just compare to 0?

Comment: @DaveNewton hmm true, what was i thinking .,, :P.